# Tkinter Message Box stuck in loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I've just gotten started with making GUIs in python using tkinter. I made a program that would generate random passwords... it still lacks bunch of stuff like save passwords and viewing saved passwords. So the problem is I added an error handling where the user would give the length of password so that we only get integers not strings... as soon as the error dialogue pops up it wont close unless I terminate it from pycharm.

```
def error(self):
    self.messagebox.showerror("Oops!","Invalid input Integers only!")
    l = int(len(entr1.get()))
    while True:
        try:
            entr1.update()
            lt = abs(int(entr1.get()))
            break
        except ValueError:
            entr1.delete(0,l)
            entr1.update()
            self.error()
```

Above is my error handling routine, entr1 is the entry box, above that is the error message box that will get displayed.
Please tell me how i can fix it... thanks in advance!

Comment: You call `error()` method recursively, the last line.

Comment: The lines after self.messagebox...
Belong to a different function, the error box should get displayed but should go away and allow the user to try entering the value again. I think thar the value of entr1.get() does get updated that is why it causes a prblm... Plz tell how to fix this issue...

Comment: Upadte ive found what i was doing wrong....fix it now it works like a charm

Comment: You can give that fix in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Fix: Used if statement instead of while True loop.

```
def error(self):
self.messagebox.showerror("Oops!","Invalid input Integers only!")


def gen(self):
    try:
        entr1.update()
        lt = abs(int(entr1.get()))
        suc = 1
    except:
        entr1.delete(0, END)
        entr1.update()
        self.error()
        suc = 0
    if suc == 1:
        tex1.delete('1.0', END)
        tex1.update()
        for x in range(21):
            password = ""
            for i in range(lt):
                randa = self.random.choice(self.al)
                randn = str(self.random.randint(0,9))
                rand = [randa, randn]
                password += self.random.choice(rand)
            tex1.insert("1.0", "{}\n".format(password))
```

the suc short for success variable keeps track of the error handling and the program is only executed if suc = 1 , al is a list containing all alphabets, tex1 is the text field